# Showing a linear map to be bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, closed-graph

Let $1 \leq p,q \leq \infty$ and $A= (a_{ij})$ be a scalar matrix. Suppose for every $x= x_j$, the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_{ij}x_j$ is convergent for every
$i$ and that $y=(y_i) \in {l}^q$ where $y_i = \sum_{1}^{\infty}a_{ij}x_j = (Ax)_{j}$. I need to show that the map $A : l^p \rightarrow l^q $ is a bounded linear map.

The hint given to me was to use *Closed graph theorem* but I don't know where to start?